# How can grep be used for this purpose?

Tags: unix

In an organisation one wants to know how many programmers are there. The employee data is stored in a file called ‘personnel’ with one record per employee. Every record has field for designation. How can grep be used for this purpose?

in addition

In the organisation mentioned above how can **sed** be used to print only the records of all employees who are programmers.

In the organisation mentioned above how can **sed** be used to change the designation ‘programmer’ to ‘software professional’ every where in the ‘personnel’ file

Comment: sounds suspiciously like homework.  if it is, what have you done to solve the problem yourself?

Comment: I agree with @atk, with the added question of "if it's *not* homework, what have you done to solve the problem yourself"?

Comment: User/admin task, not programming...

Answer (score 0):

The grep man page:

> SYNOPSIS
>          grep [options] PATTERN [FILE...]
>          grep [options] [-e PATTERN | -f FILE] [FILE...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>          Grep searches the named input FILEs (or standard input if no files
>   are named, or the
>          file name - is given) for lines  containing  a  match  to  the  given 
>   PATTERN.   By
>          default, grep prints the matching lines.

Probably grep has an option to count the number of matching lines and return that number, rather than printing the lines themselves. A quick search of the man page should tell you what it is.

The sed man file has this to say:

> NAME
>        sed -- stream editor
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        sed [-Ealn] command [file ...]
>        sed [-Ealn] [-e command] [-f command_file] [-i extension] [file
>   ...]
>
> DESCRIPTION
>        The sed utility reads the specified files, or the standard input
>   if no files are spec-
>        ified, modifying the input as specified by a list of commands.  The
>   input is then
>        written to the standard output.
>
> ```
>  A single command may be specified as the first argument to sed.
> ```
>
> Multiple commands may
>        be specified by using the -e or -f options.  All commands are applied to the input in
>        the order they are specified regardless of their origin.

That looks a little more complicated, but if you google "how to replace text with sed" you'll get [some instructions](http://drupal.org/node/128513) on how to do that.